# Entity Framework - Getting dozens of similar queries while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an application that I did not set up myself. My current way of working is writing T-SQL scripts to migrate the database manually. This works really well for me.

However when I start debugging I get (and I don't get it all the time it seems?) a lot queries that seem to be related to migrating the database. Some examples:

```
IF db_id(N'dbname') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'dbname'
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=@Table
```

I see those a lot repeated repeated repeated repeated.

I tried this so far:

```
public class MyConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfig()
    {
        SetDatabaseInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }
}
```

...and:

```
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }
```

Those breakpoints get hit so those initialisers shouldn't be set anymore. Yet it seems it tries to do some kind of table scanning for every table I touch for every time I load a page.

In production this doesn't seem to happen....but it's really hard to fix (real) performance problems if pages load north of 10 seconds by default...

Comment: If this is a web project, how many db contexts are created in each request?

Comment: Hi @jao, I was looking a bit more in the past few days and it could easily be 40 times for some pages. If I tried to buffer the contexts to a static variable they would be disposed at a certain moment during the page and crash the page load.

Comment: What about injecting the dbcontext? http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx (not sure if that works for 40 different contexts, but if those 40 are always the same, it might be better performance-wise to inject them only once)